# libevent and non-blocking sockets

Tags: c, sockets, libevent

I understand that in order to monitor a socket using libevent,  `event_set()` should first be called with the correct parameters.

The libevent documentation states that the `event` parameter to event_set() can be either EV_READ or EV_WRITE. And that this event parameter is the event to look out for.

But what socket events do EV_READ and EV_WRITE correspond to? I mean how would I monitor for a change in connection status, versus monitor for an incoming message?

Comment: IIRC: if a connection is closed you get a normal read/write event, and when you attempt to read/write you get zero bytes read/written. When you write you may also get a SIGPIPE. This is your indication that the connection is closed by the other side.

Answer (score 4):

I've found [this site](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/TOC.html) to be excellent in terms of documentation for libevent. On [the page dealing with events](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref4_event.html), there's a nice overview of what different event flags actually mean. From that link:

> - **EV_READ** : This flag indicates an event that becomes active when
>     the provided file descriptor is ready for reading.
> - **EV_WRITE** : This flag indicates an event that becomes active
>     when the provided file descriptor is ready for writing.
> - **EV_SIGNAL** : Used to implement signal detection.
> - **EV_PERSIST** : Indicates that the event is persistent.
> - **EV_ET** : Indicates that the event should be edge-triggered, if
>     the underlying event_base backend supports edge-triggered events.
>     This affects the semantics of EV_READ and EV_WRITE.

So to answer your question explicitly: EV_READ corresponds to having data available to be read from the socket or bufferevent, which are the libevent socket equivalents as far as I can tell. EV_WRITE corresponds to the socket/bufferevent being ready to have data written to it. You can set read / write callbacks to actually do the data reading and writing with the `cb` argument to

`struct event *event_new(struct event_base *base, evutil_socket_t fd,
                        short what, event_callback_fn cb, void *arg);`

If you're doing socket IO with libevent, though, you may really want to consider using [buffer events](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref6_bufferevent.html) - they're what I use in one of my projects, snot_mon, [which you can check out over on github](https://github.com/pennsnoplus/snot_mon/blob/master/snotstream.c).